# Extracting a JSON object from the event

Tags: javascript, json, service-worker

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event){
     var obj = event.data.json();
     if(obj.action==='subscribe'||obj.action==='unsubscribe'){
            fireNotification(obj,event);
            port.postMessage(obj);
     }else if(obj.action==='init'||obj.action==='chatMsg'){
            port.postMessage(obj);
     }
});
```

I am getting the "Cannot read property 'json' of undefined" error when i try running the code. Can anyone please suggest an alternative way for this

Comment: What is `self`? What does `event` contains? It's clear from the error that there is no property `data` in `event`

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying this in Chrome today the issue is that Chrome doesn't currently support the data attribute of push events, which is to say you cannot send payload with a push message in the normal GCM way.

Support should arrive in Chrome early in 2016, but for now you will have to make a fetch request to your server to retrieve the data payload required to show a notification.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web thanks mate, i got this article for the alternate but I am not sure about what to pass in fetch(SOME_API_ENDPOINT)

Comment: I would recommend that whatever triggered the notification in the backend should write that to a database (e.g. new comment with id 11, new message with id 44 etc). When the client receives a push message it should make a request to get the new entries in that notifications table (or however it is implemented) which will tell the client what the new notifications were about. The fetch will likely need to include some cookie or session token so you can pass back just the notifications for the given user.

Answer (score 0):

You should test if data exists before asking for the json()

like

```
if (typeof event.data === 'undefined') { return; }
```